# Change the specific paragraph into Gothic font?

Tags: fonts, pgothic

Just wanted to ask if how can I change the font of my specific paragraph ? Want to change only the paragraph "  Change this font into MS Gothic " without running any compiller.

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \title{Font Gothic}
  \author{Udot}
  \date{September 2022}

  \begin{document}

  \maketitle

  \section{Introduction}

  {Change this font into MS Gothic}


  {Don't change this font}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps your question is mis-understood. Do you wish to change the font that is used for showing the plain text file, before it is compiled? In other words, the font that will be used in the PDF is not affected, only what you see when writing your document is affected? If that is the case, I believe there are some GUI editors with that capability (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Run with `XeLaTeX`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\msgothic{MS Gothic}
\title{Font Gothic}
\author{Udot}
\date{September 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
{\msgothic Change this font into MS Gothic}

Don't change this font
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if I do not run in any compiler.

Comment: How do you process a LaTeX file? Perhaps via `pdflatex`? That is not a compiler neither is XeLaTeX